# How to estimate ambient light intensity and color from camera image for Augmented reality application?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

ARKit and ARCore has the feature to estimate the ambient light intensity and color for realistic rendering.

ARKit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate?language=objc

ARCore: https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/LightEstimate#getColorCorrection(float[],%20int)

They both expose an ambient intensity and an ambient color. In ARKit, the color is in degrees kelvin while in ARCore it is RGB color correction.

Question 1: What's the difference between kelvin and color correction and how can they be applied to rendering?

Question 2: What's the algorithm to estimate the light intensity and color from camera frames? Are there existing code or research papers we can refer to if we want to implement it ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Question 2 for ARCore: 
Here is a research paper on [How Environmental HDR works](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/LeGendre_DeepLight_Learning_Illumination_for_Unconstrained_Mobile_Mixed_Reality_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf)

Here is a short summary about [environmental HDR in ARCore + Sceneform](https://creativetech.blog/home/environmental-hdr-arcore)

Hope it helps you in your search :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The paper was referenced by Google engineers when they announced the realistic rendering feature in Google IO 2019. The paper talks about environmental HDR lighting, which is a more advanced feature than ambient lighting. 

I wonder if there are simpler algorithm that can just give the ambient light intensity and color. Is it as simple as just averaging the intensity and RGB color of each pixel in the image?

Answer (score 1):

Providing you have added a light node called 'light' with a `SCNLight` attached to it in your "ship.scn" `SCNScene` and that your `ViewController` conforms to ARSessionDelegate so you can get the light estimate per frame:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {

@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    sceneView.scene = scene
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    sceneView.session.delegate = self
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    guard let lightEstimate = frame.lightEstimate,
    let light = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "light", recursively: false)?.light else {return}
    light.temperature = lightEstimate.ambientColorTemperature
    light.intensity = lightEstimate.ambientIntensity
}

}
```

As a result, if you dim the lights in your room, SceneKit will dim the virtual light too .

[image: ARKit light estimation]